# Accented/encoded characters are not displaying properly

Tags: php, character-encoding

Content:

```
      Crescimento da economia Trabalhador com baixa remuneração ocupa 63% das vagas no país
```

But this getting displayed as in a Php page

```
      Crescimento da economiaTrabalhador com baixa remuneraÃ§Ã£o ocupa 63% das vagas no paÃ­s
```

How to convert the characters using a proper encoding? What is the function I should use to get the same content as the above without any characters like this "Ã§Ã"

Comment: Looks like you're using the wrong character encoding. Where are you fetching the strings from? What encoding did you save the file with? What encoding are you sending in your HTTP headers? You should be using the same encoding everywhere, and that encoding should preferably be UTF-8.

Comment: I am getting those content from a webpage which uses "UTF-8" and I am displaying it in a page which also uses "UTF-8"

Whether there is any way to detect that the string is not character encoded properly?

Comment: Did you save the file with UTF-8 encoding? Sometimes editors prepend a Byte-Order Mark (BOM) that can screw things up. The problem is that we can't really help without seeing *how* you're serving the content encoding type.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms are clear: when the characters ç and ã appear in data as UTF-8 encoded (as byte pairs C3 A7 and C3 A3) but the data is interpreted according to ISO-8859-1 or some similar encoding, you get Ã§ and Ã£ (as Ã = C3, § = A7, and £ = A3 in ISO-8859-1). Thus, you probably get the data OK but the page where you put it is not UTF-8 encoded; note that HTTP headers, if they specify the encoding, will override `<meta>` tags in the document.

Answer (score 0):

The previous comment is correct.  Try playing with the PHP function [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) as well as the meta tags in the page head and if possible headers to ensure you are presenting your content in the correct encoding.